# C++ is it possible to make array elements a single ''int'' variable?

Tags: c++, binary

I have made this program which pretty much guesses a number that the user is supposed to think, but ofc within some limits. The program then finds the answer but in binary numbers(1,0) and I'm supposed to convert it to decimal. I have created an array that saves the binary number which I'm supposed to convert. I have also created a binary converter. The thing is I can't think of a way to put the array on the actual function to convert it to a decimal number. I really need help from an expert.

```cpp
//Binary converter

int BinaryToDecimal(int n) {
    int decimalNumber = 0;
    int base = 1;
    int temp = n;
    while (temp) {
        int lastDigit = temp % 10;
        temp = temp / 10;
        decimalNumber += lastDigit * base;
        base = base * 2;
    }
    cout << "Decimal form of " << n << " is " << decimalNumber << endl;

    return n;
}
```

```cpp
case 6:
    cout << ", think of a number between 1 and 63 and i will guess it..." << endl;
    cout << "1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39 41 43 45 47 49 51 53 55 57 59 61 63 " << endl << "Is your number in the above table?(y/n): ";
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 'y' && 'Y') { answer[1] = 1; }
    else { answer[1] = 0; }

    cout << "2 3 6 7 10 11 14 15 18 19 22 23 26 27 30 31 34 35 38 39 42 43 46 47 50 51 54 55 58 59 62 63 " << endl << "Is your number in the above table?(y/n): ";
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 'y' && 'Y') { answer[2] = 1; }
    else { answer[2] = 0; }

    cout << "4 5 6 7 12 13 14 15 20 21 22 23 28 29 30 31 36 37 38 39 44 45 46 47 52 53 54 55 60 61 62 63" << endl << "Is your number in the above table?(y/n): ";
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 'y' && 'Y') { answer[3] = 1; }
    else { answer[3] = 0; }

    cout << "8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 " << endl << "Is your number in the above table?(y/n): ";
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 'y' && 'Y') { answer[4] = 1; }
    else { answer[4] = 0; }

    cout << "16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63" << endl << "Is your number in the above table?(y/n): ";
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 'y' && 'Y') { answer[5] = 1; }
    else { answer[5] = 0; }

    cout << "32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 " << endl << "Is your number in the above table?(y/n): ";
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 'y' && 'Y') { answer[6] = 1; }
    else { answer[6] = 0; }

    for (int i = size; i > 0; i--) { cout << answer[i]; }

    cout << BinaryToDecimal(); **//My problem lies here. How can i put answer[] into this fucntion to convert it.**
        break;
}
```

EDIT: I managed to make this work!!. Thanks a lot!

```
case 6:
        cout << ", think of a number between 1 and 63 and i will guess it..." << endl;
        cout << "1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39 41 43 45 47 49 51 53 55 57 59 61 63 " << endl << "Is your number in the above table?(y/n): ";
        cin >> choice;
        if ((choice == 'y') || (choice == 'Y')) { answer[0] = 1; }
        else { answer[0] = 0; }

        cout << "2 3 6 7 10 11 14 15 18 19 22 23 26 27 30 31 34 35 38 39 42 43 46 47 50 51 54 55 58 59 62 63 " << endl << "Is your number in the above table?(y/n): ";
        cin >> choice;
        if ((choice == 'y') || (choice == 'Y')) { answer[1] = 1; }
        else { answer[1] = 0; }

        cout << "4 5 6 7 12 13 14 15 20 21 22 23 28 29 30 31 36 37 38 39 44 45 46 47 52 53 54 55 60 61 62 63" << endl << "Is your number in the above table?(y/n): ";
        cin >> choice;
        if ((choice == 'y') || (choice == 'Y')) { answer[2] = 1; }
        else { answer[2] = 0; }

        cout << "8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 " << endl << "Is your number in the above table?(y/n): ";
        cin >> choice;
        if ((choice == 'y') || (choice == 'Y')) { answer[3] = 1; }
        else { answer[3] = 0; }

        cout << "16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63" << endl << "Is your number in the above table?(y/n): ";
        cin >> choice;
        if ((choice == 'y') || (choice == 'Y')) { answer[4] = 1; }
        else { answer[4] = 0; }

        cout << "32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 " << endl << "Is your number in the above table?(y/n): ";
        cin >> choice;
        if ((choice == 'y') || (choice == 'Y')) { answer[5] = 1; }
        else {
            answer[5] = 0;
        }

        break;
    }
    //reverses(answer, n);
    int b = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        b += answer[i] * pow(2, i);

    cout << "The number your are thinking is hmm, " << b << " hehe." << endl;


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To be honest, the easier solution is to convert your array directly to an integer value, rather than trying to convert it to a form suitable for your BinaryToDecimal function. It's a simple loop to do this, and it looks like you already have the math skills to work this out.

Comment: Thomas Sablik that's exactly what I'm trying to do :/...

Comment: FYI, see `std::toupper` and `std::tolower` to convert your `choice` variable to upper case or lower case, so you'll only need to compare once.

Comment: BTW, `(choice == 'y' && 'Y')` doesn't function like you expect.  If we add parenthesis according to operator precedence, the expression is: `((choice == 'y') && ('Y'))`.  You'll need to make it `((choice == 'y') || (choice == 'Y'))`  Notice the switch between AND and OR.  A character can't have two values simultaneously (the AND condition).

Comment: You are correct that was a foolish mistake.

Comment: @Pneuma you should have posted your solution as a separate answer, not as an edit to your question. You can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the array of 6 "bits" to an `int` like this:

```
int b = std::accumulate(answer, answer + 6, 0,
                        [](auto sum, auto bit) { return sum * 2 + bit; });
```

This is effectively what `BinaryToDecimal` does internally, so you don't even really need the function. Besides, storing a number like `5` as decimal `101` is a roundabout way of converting between bases.

You are not indexing the array properly however. Since you are only taking in inputs that have 6 bits, `answer` only needs to be an `int[6]`, in which case you should index from `0` to `5`.

Comment: @ThomasSablik yeah, I didn't spot that. Edited the answer.

Comment: Can you explain a bit the index part? . I tried to change my arrays from 0-5 but I got the wrong results.

Comment: Change your indices such that the 1st element is at position 0, the 2nd at position 1, and so on. Make sure you do all the changes consistently.

Comment: Also, do I need a specific library for ''accumulate''? . It doesn't let me use it.

Comment: It's in the `numeric` header.

Comment: So this code converts my array to decimal pretty much?. I'm a bit confused sorry.

Comment: Try and work it out with pen and paper. if you wrote the binaryToDecimal yourself, you'll quickly figure out what this is doing.

Comment: There is btw a small issue. The number I'm looking for let's say is for example 13 while the console outputs 44. It's the same binary code but I need it the other way around ''001101' - ''101100''

Comment: You could iterate in reverse with `rbegin` and `rend`, or you could `reverse` the array before accumulating.